# it seems to be that?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I was curious about the original structure of the sentences.

> It seems correct.

Original version:

> It seems to be correct.

Well, it is a very well known fact.

But what about the ones that use that clause and like/as if clause?

Is it possible to say that the original structure, or the implied structure is as below?

> It seems that he is hurt.

Original version:

> It seems to be that he is hurt.

and

> It seems like/as if he is hurt.

Original version:

> It seems to be like/as if he is hurt.

When I googled "it seems to be that", there were quite many examples, and it doesn't sound completely off to me, where as "it seems to be like/as if" returned barely any result at all and sounds completely off.

Is my analysis correct, or are these two sentences with seem as a linking verb something completely different?